# Logstash jdbc not sending data

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I'm trying to export datas from a mysql table to elastic search with logstash and the jdbc mysql driver with every process in a docker container. My problem is (with no error) their is nothing sent to elastic search.

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM elastic/logstash:6.3.0

ENV https_proxy=
ENV http_proxy=

COPY ./mysql-connector-java-5.1.46/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar /tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar
COPY ./logstash.conf /tmp/logstash.conf
COPY ./logstash.yml /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml

RUN logstash-plugin install logstash-input-jdbc
```

I run it with this command :

```
docker run -d --rm --name=logstach -v /data/logstash:/home/logstash logstash bin/logstash -f /tmp/logstash.conf
```

And here is my logstash.conf :

```
input {
        jdbc {
            jdbc_driver_library => "/tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://0.0.2.22:3306/itop_db"
           jdbc_user => "admin"
            jdbc_password => "password"
            statement => "SELECT * FROM contact”
        }
    }
    output {
         elasticsearch {
            index => "contact"
            document_type => "data"
            document_id => "%{id}"
            hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"
        }
        stdout { codec => json_lines }
    }
```

Every thing seems to accomplish well, except their is no new index in elastic search http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v

This is the output I have when i run logstash :

[logstash execution output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKuQQ.png)

[logstash error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQMku.png)

Comment: Your MySQL server IP address is wrong

Comment: Are you sur that the address 0.0.2.22:3306 is recheable from the logstash container?
Try to execut a  `ping`, `telnet` or `curl` command

Comment: The mysql IP is good, I just changed the 2 first numbers by 0.0. I can connect to mysql with the infos in the jdbc input from the same machine I execute the docker run.
I mean this works : 
 `mysql -h "0.0.2.22" -u admin -ppassword `

Comment: Can you show us Logstash's logs?

Comment: Yes, done. this is the output of the command I use to run logstash

Answer (score 1):

`"SELECT * FROM contact”` <-- this could be the problem. I imagine you copied this from the internet? Change `”` to `"`

Comment: Oh, thank you. Did not seen that. The sql command was copied from a word document I think.
I now have connection refused from elastic search, but I'll try to resolv it on my own

Comment: I think the default docker image of ES has x-pack enabled, might need to disable it or provide creds.

Comment: You think it could be my problem ? I updated my first message

Comment: Ah, I think you have the IP of ES wrong? Unless it's running on the same node as Logstash (doesn't appear to be from the Dockerfile).

Comment: Yes, I am running thoses services on the same machine. I run ES with the default image with no modification though.

Comment: But ES is running in a different container (as I can't see any mention of it in your Logstash Dockerfile)? If so, `127.0.0.1` is not the right IP to connect to. You need the IP of the ES container.

Comment: I think as the container is listening on 0.0.0.0:9200, I can give its direct ip (172.17.0.2 in my case) or the 127.0.0.1 and both should work.

Comment: It is now working, I have made some errors while testing and it is fixed. I have a new index (contact) in my ES instance. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the error in my SQL statement, I needed to specify the host ip of the container (172.17.0.2 in my case) instead of using 127.0.0.1:9200